# How do I automatically add dlls to ironruby engine

Tags: ironruby

I want to automatically add loaded dll of the current application into ironruby engine so that each time I execute a script I won't specify the "require" script anymore.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[I did this in September 2008](http://blog.orionedwards.com/2008/09/embedded-ironruby-interactive-console.html) using `ScriptRuntime.LoadAssembly`. Here's my original code

```
// this part may have changed, there's probably a different
// way to get the ScriptRuntime from the RubyEngine or somesuch
var runtime = new ScriptRuntime( Ruby.CreateRuntimeSetup() ); 

// give ruby access to all our assemblies
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    runtime.LoadAssembly(assembly);
}
```

Comment: Yep, Orion is correct; ScriptRuntime#LoadAssembly is the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use IronRuby.Ruby.RequireFile in order to load a script file only once.

For example, the next line loads the CSV library from the standard library folder:

```
IronRuby.Ruby.RequireFile(engine, @"D:\IronRuby\lib\ruby\1.8\csv.rb");
```

Hope it helps,

Shay.

Comment: The latest version has the RequireRubyFile but I don't know if this supports dll's. I'll go check it out.